# Gatsby Link Resets Apollo Client

Tags: javascript, redux, gatsby, apollo, apollo-client

I am trying to implement **Gatsby with Apollo Client**

Here is my *gatsby-browser.js* file

```
export const wrapPageElement = ({ element, props }) => {
  const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: "http://localhost:3000/graphql",
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    credentials: "include",
  });
  window.a = client;
  return (
    <CookiesProvider>
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <ChakraProvider theme={theme} {...props}>
          {element}
        </ChakraProvider>
      </ApolloProvider>
    </CookiesProvider>
  );
};
```

I am persisting my logged in user details in GraphQL cache so that it can be accessed anywhere in my application. Here is the code of logging in

```
 const [login, { data, error }] = useMutation(AUTH_USER, {
    onCompleted: ({ login: data }) => {
      try {
        client.writeFragment({
          id: "me",
          fragment: FRAGMENTS_USER.all_details,
          data: data,
        });
        setToken(data.token);
      } catch (e) {}
    },
  });
```

**My problem** is that the cache is being reset on navigation. So, using *gatsby-link* or *gatsby-navigation* is resetting my cache

I have been using NextJS, and it is the first time I am writing applications in Gatsby, but it doesn't seem to behave like a Single-Page application in that case.

Answer (score 0):

`wrapPageElement` and `wrapRootElement` APIs need to be used across `gatsby-browser.js` and `gatsby-ssr.js`. Both files need to share the same content to avoid persistence errors. So, in your `gatsby-ssr.js`:

```
export const wrapPageElement = ({ element, props }) => {
  const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: "http://localhost:3000/graphql",
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    credentials: "include",
  });
  window.a = client;
  return (
    <CookiesProvider>
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <ChakraProvider theme={theme} {...props}>
          {element}
        </ChakraProvider>
      </ApolloProvider>
    </CookiesProvider>
  );
};
```

As  you can see in [Gatsby's docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-ssr/#wrapPageElement):

> Note: There is an equivalent hook in [Gatsby’s Browser](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/browser-apis/#wrapRootElement) API. It is
> recommended to use both APIs together. For example usage, check out
> [Using redux](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/examples/using-redux).

Maybe this fixes your issue.